# jQuery: on scroll, DIV always at the bottom right of whatever is viewable

Tags: jquery, scroll, position, css-position

I'm trying to determine the best way to make sure that a specific DIV is always 20px from the bottom and 20px from the right, even once a user scrolls.

```
<body>
<div id="wrap">
<p>Some content</p>
</div>
<div class="social-badges"><!-- this is the box that will always be at the bottom right --></div>
</body>

$(window).scroll(function() {
        console.log('scrolling');
        $(".tba-social-slider").css({"position" : "absolute", "bottom" : "20px", "right" : "20px"});
    });
```

Comment: so what's wrong with your code? you told us what you are trying to achieve but not what's currently happening

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS position fixed should do the trick:

```
.tba-social-slider{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}
```

No Javascript needed IMO.

Comment: Yeah, no need for javascript for this one.

Comment: Agreed. Thanks for getting rid of the cobwebs. :)

Answer (score 0):

This code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var div = $('.social-badges');
    var start = $(div).offset().top;

    $.event.add(window, "scroll", function() {
        var p = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
        $(div).css('position',((p)>start) ? 'fixed' : 'static');
        $(div).css('top',((p)>start) ? '5px' : '');
    });
});
```

That should work, but not sure. :)

Comment: Some tips: `div` is already a jQuery object, so no need for `$(div)`. Also you can use chaining like `.css(...).css(...)` or even `.css({ ... })`.

Comment: This isn't my code. I got this actually from another stack overflow that I had used myself in the past. Thank you though. :)